# Migrating to MonoTouch from Xcode - iPhone

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, xcode, xamarin.ios

We're migrating our dev shop away from XCode to MonoTouch.

In Objective-C, the [super] is the same as a call to base in C#?

Comment: Just curious, why are you migrating away from Xcode?

Comment: Less code to write for the same app functions, and access to a lot more developers (.NET). Simply put we can deliver many more apps in the same time as we can in Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, the base keyword is used to access members of the base class from within a derived class:

Call a method on the base class that has been overridden by another method.

```
public override void Foo()
{
    base.Foo();
}
```

Specify which base-class constructor should be called when creating instances of the derived class.

```
class Bar : Baz
{
    Bar( string s ) : base(s)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Migration to XCode is one interesting topic I will be covering on my blog.
http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2011/04/29/porting-application-from-ios-to-wp7c-some-toughts-migration-of-objective-c-to-c.aspx
This first post just shows a basic map of .h and .m @interface and @implementation to C#.